# Eventstore dispatch flag set to true on restart

Tags: cqrs, neventstore

I am using JOliver's EventStore and for now I am using a synchronous dispatcher so that when the command comes in, it is processed by my command handler then persisted in the event store and then my event handler update my read model. At this stage I am not using NServiceBus but I hope to introduce it later. My eventstore database and readmodel are on the same machine.

What I have noticed is that if an exception is raised in my event handler (and also since I am not using DTC) the event is committed in the eventstore and the dispatch flag is set to false. This is what I expected but when I restart my server, the flag is set to true but the event handler code is never called.

Any ideas why this is happening?

I assumed any non-dispatched events would get dispatched or there would be some retry mechanism in the event store code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not very mistaken, the dispatch flag  set to false should occur once the event is stored. Typically you would do an initialization of your event store like this when starting your application :

```
var storeEvents = Wireup.Init()
                  ...
                  .DispatchTo(new DelegateMessageDispatcher(dispatcher.dispatchCommit)
                  .Build();
```

The flag is set to false before this action occurs *dispatcher.dispatchCommit* and to true once this action is a success.

are you not confused with event handler in your aggregate ?

```
public void Apply(MystuffDone evt)
{
   //code...
}
```

Comment: My response was more a question about whether or not you were confused with event handler from aggregate and event handler from projection. I had some doubt reading your question about what you meant exactly....

Comment: because there is a retry mechanism for non dispatched events in the J. Oliver's ES .

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. Just to be clear, the retry mechanism in J. Oliver's ES does not seem to fire off the projection event handler code when an error is raised the first time. Have you noticed this?

Comment: Nope. A friend of mine had the exact same problem in production with a server that has been shut down. And the events not dispatched were successfully re-dispatched and their flag set to true after restarting it. I have not tested this particular scenario so far myself. When I find some time, I try to reproduce it and let  you know ( mmhh might be in a couple of month though.. :p ) good luck!

Comment: Dispatched is only sent to true once the message "bus" (NServiceBus, MassTransit, etc.) has acknowledged full responsibility for the message.